# Проблемы с SSR в Angular

Tags: typescript, angular, ssr

Не получается запустить SSR. Делал все как по инструкции на сайте. Может что не так настроил. Кто хорошо понимает подскажите что я сделал не так :)
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:52279

[package.json and angular.json Скачать](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eNnpSCuZKCTGGRvrgXj2L9y5f0KrbUtg/view?usp=sharing)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая версия ноды? и порт пробовали поменять?

Comment: Нода  последняя 16. Порт запуска самого ангуляра?

Comment: да, сервера 52279 вот этот, кажется в server.ts должно быть

Comment: Что интересно у меня нигде такого порта не прописано. Он сгенерированный какой то

Comment: process.env.PORT - вот это там по идее должно быть, нужно поменять допустим на 443 и посмотреть как работать будет

Comment: Не подскажешь где искать value  у process.env.PORT? У меня в стандартном environmend нет такого свойства  порт?

Comment: server.ts функция run

Comment: попробуйте вот этот 11й стартер [универсала](https://github.com/Angular-RU/universal-starter). Angular CLI- 11.2.10, node - v16.4.0 npm - 7.18.1

Comment: там просто склонировать гит ->`npm i` -> `npm run start`

Comment: у меня в server.ts  я принудительно ставлю порт. Он все равно другой показывает.

Comment: а команду какую запускаете?

Comment: npm run dev:ssr

Comment: делал по этому https://angular.io/guide/universal но не хочет

Comment: еще вопрос возможно ли как то исключать компоненты из ssr? может у меня какие компоненты не хочет билдить

Comment: Сейчас попробовал с нуля поставить тоже не сразу получилось. dist/PROJECT/ not found. Поставил сначала ангулар  потом ng add @nguniversal/express-engine. Потом npm run dev:ssr

Comment: Тогда сделал по другому: поставил ангулар ng new some-app, сделал билд  ng build, добавил ng add @nguniversal/express-engine затем npm i. Ну и npm run dev:ssr

Comment: Конечно зависимости могут играть роль. Попробовать можно так: создать новый ангулар проект с универсалом, если он запускается, тогда следующим шагом добавлять зависимости из вашего пакета. После каждой зависимости собирать проект

Comment: Попробуйте стартер который выше давал ссылку. На него навешивать ваши пакеты. 52279-й порт не понятно откуда он, может что то у вас в проекте или в пакете каком-то вызывается

Comment: `process.env.PORT` это порт, который непросредственно слушает процесс ноды. `52279` это порт `browser-sync`, который перезагружает страницу, когда ты делаешь какое-либо изменение в файлах, он выбирается рандомно, в следующий раз может быть совершенно иным. Ошибка, которую ты видишь, часто возникает если у тебя произошли ошибки компиляции. Это связано с тем, что nguniversal пытается ре-ранить dev-ssr executor, он спавнит инстанс browser-sync и заново конектится к тому порту, но предыдущий инстанс browser-sync не успел освободить порт. Рестарт должен всегда помогать

Comment: а если я первый раз жму dev:ssr и он такую фигачит ошибку?

Comment: ищи ошибки в коде, я вижу там `ScrollBlot`, возможно ты импортируешь quill статически, а не только в браузере внутри `isPlatformBrowser` условия, поэтому нода пытается выполнить код и падает с ошибкой `document is not defined`, потому что quill добавляет обработчики событий. Все что угодно может быть, я из твоего скрина бОльшего тебе сказать не могу